# Wrap legend text containing expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have been looking for a wrapper function in ggplot2 which can help me put the legend text in a defined rectangular area.

So far I haven't found one. Here is my case:

```
library (ggplot2)
p = ggplot (mtcars, aes (x = mpg, y= cyl,color = factor (cyl)))
p + geom_point()
z = unique (factor (mtcars$cyl))
p + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(name="legend title", breaks = z, 
                                  labels = c (expression(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i), expression(x) ,  expression(y ) ),
                                  values = c("red","blue","green") )
```

What I want is to have the long expression wrapped within a width of **five characters**.

Is there any function which can automatically wrap each legend key's text in a defined text width, and I am wondering if that can also be applicable for expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The following, using `str_wrap` from `stringr`, should work for you.  It wraps using a value of 5 as requested, but doesn't look that great.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
p = ggplot (mtcars, aes (x = mpg, y= cyl,color = factor (cyl)))
p + geom_point()
z = unique (factor (mtcars$cyl))
p + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(name="legend title", breaks = z, 
                                      labels = c(str_wrap(expression(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i), 5), expression(x) ,  expression(y ) ),
                                      values = c("red","blue","green") )
```

[image]

Comment: @stevebI have tried this one. But once I make the expression more complex (like introducing subscript and superscript) it does not seem to work. Let

Comment: @satyanarayanrao Can you include the code you have for the super and subscripts.  I can look at those but focusing you your specific case would be a good place to start.

Comment: Here it is: 
  str = paste ("P[\"", "a","\"]^m*Q*", "P[\"", "b",  "\"]^m*Q", sep="")
In the ggplot: 
    labels = c (str_wrap(parse (text = str), 15), expression(x) ,  expression(y ) )
Here the expression does not comes out as expected. Actually I have a long string of such expression, and I want to wrap it.

Comment: A possible alternative could be to put the legend on the bottom using something like the following `+ theme(legend.position="bottom") + guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 3))`.

Comment: Thanks, steveb, Finally I ended up using Inkscape. I find it too hard to fit them in a matrix form.